# Reverse SSH connection at startup?

Tags: linux, boot, ssh, cron, reverse-tunnel

I have a Raspberry Pi, running Kali Linux. What I want it to do is, as soon as it boots, to connect with a reverse SSH connection to my machine at home, so I can control it wherever it is.

I created a script, that I called connect.sh, with this line in it:

```
sshpass -p '******' ssh -R 12345:localhost:***** user@**.***.**.** -p ***** -N &
```

And I added

```
@reboot /root/connect.sh
```

To crontab (I edited it with crontab -e). The issue is, the command works when I manually execute the script, but when I reboot the Raspberry Pi and try to connect to it with my other machine, it doesn't work. And if I execute the script manually, it does.

So I assume there's a problem in the execute-on-startup thing. And I know the script does execute, because I added `echo test > test` at the beginning of connect.sh, and when I reboot the Pi, the file is there. So there's a problem with the SSH command.

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe your `connect` script is running before the network is established, and is failing because of that.  Try adding a `sleep` to the script.

Comment: @Scott Weeeeell, I'm just very dumb xD. I already tried adding a sleep command before, and it didn't work, but I think i didn't make it sleep enough, because with `sleep 60`, it works. Thank you! How do I set the question as "answered", when nobody posted an answer?

Comment: OK, I’ve reposted my suggestion as an official answer.  You know what to do now, right?  Click the checkmark to the left of the answer.  (Because you are a new user, you may need to wait a few hours before you can “accept” an answer.)

Comment: @Scott Yeah, I know how to do it with official answers, thank you again ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startup scripts sometimes start running *very* early in the boot process
— sometimes before the network is established. 
If these startup scripts try to access the network too early, they can fail. 
Adding a (sufficiently long) `sleep` to the beginning of your script
may solve the problem.